# Eager Loading of Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my repository I'm trying to use eager loading to load related entities.  Not sure why but it seems like when I return all instances of a particular entity, related entities are returned, but when I limit the results returned the related entities are not included in the results.

This code in the service layer is returning all orders, including related Customer, OrderItem, and Product entities:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOrdersAsync()
{
    return await _repository.GetAsync(null, q => q.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedDate), "Customer", "OrderItems", "OrderItems.Product");
}
```

In the repository:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> where = null, Func<IQueryable<Order>, IOrderedQueryable<Order>> orderBy = null, params string[] navigationProperties)
{
    IQueryable<Order> query = _context.Set<Order>();

    if (where != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(where);
    }

    //Apply eager loading
    foreach (string navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            query = query.Include(navigationProperty);

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

This code in the service layer is getting an order by id, but for whatever reason is not returning related Customer, OrderItem, and Product entities:

```
public async Task<Order> GetOrderByIdAsync(long id)
{
  return await _repository.GetByIdAsync(id, "Customer", "OrderItems", "OrderItems.Product");
}
```

In the repository:

```
public async Task<Order> GetByIdAsync(long id, params string[] navigationProperties)
{
    DbSet<Order> dbSet = _context.Set<Order>();

    foreach (string navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        dbSet.Include(navigationProperty);

    return await dbSet.FindAsync(id);
}
```

The one difference I see between the two repository methods is one is casting the _context.Set() to IQueryable before including navigation properties, while the other is calling Include directly on the DbSet itself.  Should this matter?

Comment: actually... I'm not soo sure IQueryable has the same Include() functionality DbSet<> does.

Answer (score 0):

So the repository method that was not working was using DBSet.Include incorrectly.  Include is actually a method on the DBQuery class, which DBSet inherits from.  I needed to use DBQuery.Include to replace the query with a new instance of the query for each navigation property I included.  So I changed the implementation to:

```
public async Task<Order> GetByIdAsync(long id, params string[] navigationProperties)
{
    DbQuery<Order> dbQuery = _context.Set<Order>();

    foreach (string navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);

    return await dbQuery.Where(o => o.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```